Does user deletion result in answer deletion?
Up until recently, there was a very active user who went by the handle "Freddy".  Freddy had supplied many good answers and I believe quite a few accepted ones.  Now, it seems both the user and all those answers are missing.
Freddy also was prickly and occasionally got into comment battles.  I therefore find it plausible that Freddy got angry, deleted all his/her comments and answers, and then removed the account.  This left QSE bereft of some good material.
I'm curious what the community thinks about this.  Is that what happened?  Should it be possible for a user to do this, and if so should we make it easier?  Or, if it should not be possible, how ought it be prevented?

Freddy changed his name to Matt Wolf.
As for user deletion of content, small-time users can "destroy" their account and get rid of everything. The mods occasionally do this for spam accounts. Once a user has enough rep, total destruction of content is prohibited. The mods are also pretty vigilant against self-destruction of content.

Ah, I see.  Still, quite a few comments and answers are now missing.
